# jQuery mobile prefetch data-icon

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have many different pages in jquery mobile which utilizing different data-icon, some custom and some are built in, is there a way to preload all of these data-icons, because now its like when a new page loads with a new icon for the first time, it will be blank for a second before it is loaded. which is annoying.

I am using phonegap+backbone+jquery mobile. so its heavy java stuff instead of pure html.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using [image sprites](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/)? This way, all icons will be cached on the first page load. It's a little extra css upfront, but I think it'd be really worth it!

Comment: I was try to use the new svg icons in jquery mobile 1.4

Comment: SVG is drawn from XML, but will fall back to jQuery mobile's PNG sprites if the browser doesn't support it. In either case, I don't think this would cause an issue. Do you have a code sample?